# Is really necessary to keep username/password into a SESSION variable?

Tags: php, webmail, hmail-server

this question is more about a concept than a code issue itself. 
I'm into some project that need a custom webmail and as I'm a Windows guy, I decided to go in the backend with hMailServer + PHP. But then, it just came the first doubt: hMailServer provides me support for a COM API, which method can be accessed via PHP, that's good. So for login, I could do something like:

```
<?php
    $obBaseApp = new COM("hMailServer.Application");
    $obBaseApp->Authenticate("email@privmail.local", "12345") or die('Invalid user');
?>
```

To get the e-mails inside the inbox of the current logged-in user, I need to do:

```
$obBaseApp = new COM("hMailServer.Application");
$obBaseApp->Authenticate("email@privmail.local", "12345") or die('Invalid user');

$obDomain = $obBaseApp->Domains->ItemByName("privmail.local");
$obAccount = $obDomain->Accounts->ItemByAddress("email@privmail.local");
$obMessage = $obAccount->Messages;
$totalMessages = $obMessage->Count;

for ($i = 0; $i < $totalMessages; $i++)
{
    echo $obMessage->Item[$i]->Subject;
}
```

Ok, so let's imagine the following scenario: in the login page, I use the first code posted above, to check if the login is valid... If it's valid, I redirect to the inbox page, where I parse all the e-mails... But to do this, I need to keep username/password saved in a session variable and worst: decrypted! This is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Once you validate a user generate a random `sha512` hash for him, save it to his DB record, attach it to session and only store `session ID` in their cookie.

This way a user's browser will request session status, your script will look up session-matching hash and then decide upon allowing access.

Additional precautions are advised: Store user agent, IP address, set session expiration time, detect idle time etc.

EDIT: Taking into account what *developerwjk* said.
If you truly need to operate on plain passwords for `hMailServer` it's terribad. Plain password should never be stored, anywhere, not in the database or session.
Upon user registration you should generate a `hash` made of their `salt + password` save it as the password and only pass it to `hMailServer`, as for identification, like I said above `session ID <-> hash <-> access`.
Every time they log in, you generate the hash again, the same way, and let them in if hashes match.

Comment: I could be mistaken, but I think he was considering keeping the password in the session because of needing to supply it to a COM object that might not understand hashed passwords...

Comment: Also, I think the question is about storing the username and password in `$_SESSION` not in a cookie.

Comment: Yes, that's my problem. If I provide a hash pass in the COM, it will give-me wrong results for authentication...

Comment: Well `$_SESSION` file is stored on the server while `session ID` is additionally used in a cookie. Thought that was relevant. I updated my answer.

Comment: I edited my answer to indicate that a password could actually be a hash which is always _one-way generated_ and the actual password is such a hash.

Comment: @user3810691 In other words, find a way to control how the mailserver saves its passwords, make it save them in hashed form, and then you can give it a hash and it will work.

Comment: I don't know, maybe I missed something, but the passwords are stored as a hash in database, but I can't supply it (the hash) in the COM API, because it will compares the hash saved in DB with the hash of a hash I supplied in the COM API.